# printing php variables in echo ''

Tags: php

i have a big table where should print 5 php variables.

I am printing this way

```
echo '

<td valign="center" align="center" colspan="2">Number : <br/>$num</td>


';
```

but it prints $num not the value of $num

EDIT :

I realized that.

```
echo '

'    <td valign="center" align="center" colspan="2">Number : <br/>'.$num.'</td>    ';
```

Thank you for help :)

Comment: That HTML comes straight out of the 90s. Please learn about CSS.

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: just change single qoutes `'` to double qoutes `"` as @CBroe suggested read the PHP manual in the link above, and you will understand the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single quoted PHP strings do not interpolate variables. Double quoted strings do. Use a double quoted string.

Better yet, don't build up HTML in strings in the first place. Drop into PHP mode only when you need access to PHP.

```
<td valign="center" align="center" colspan="2">Number : <br/><?php echo $num;?></td>
```

Comment: or concatenate the var with the string propely

Comment: Concatenating variables generally makes for the hardest code to read. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Not sure if I can concur with this. Guess its about preference on that

Comment: @DarkBee - Concatenating variables to strings is ok, but manually `echo`ing HTML is usually bad practice.

Comment: Well that is true, i'd say it's better to use a template engine for the HTML part anyway, while other will claim PHP is a template engine on its own

Comment: Not trivial pages are better off with a full template engine. PHP is a template engine on its own, but not a very good one.

Comment: @DarkBee please explain about full template engine ... btw i solved my problem thank you guys

Comment: @dongou have a look at [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) as an example. When u use a full template engine your able to seperate PHP logic with your views (HTML). This way your code will be more readable. [here](http://www.sitecrafting.com/blog/top-5-php-template-engines) you can find a more detailed explanation on template engines and a variety of them.